ContentDocumentLink Trigger referencing User Object for LInkedEntityID
I have a requirement to create an Email notification when an attachment is added to a custom object. I have seen other questions and resolutions here that reference the fact that LinkedEntityId cannot reference a custom object but instead will always reference the User - which is the behavior I am observing when the trigger executes. In some examples I have seen, people state that the trigger fires twice, once for the user and once for the parent record it's being attached to and thus I have the following code to check for the type of sObject entering the trigger logic:
trigger ContentAttachmentTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {

set<Id> requestIds = new Set<Id>();
set<Id> documentIds = new Set<Id>();

system.debug('The trigger fired.');

for (ContentDocumentLink cd : Trigger.new)
{
    //Define the type of SObject being consumed by the trigger
    Schema.sObjectType ObjectType = cd.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType();

//Check if SObject is what I want aka NOT the user object
if( cd.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() == Custom_Object__c.sObjectType)
    {
    
        requestIds.add(cd.LinkedEntityId);
        documentIds.add(cd.Id);
        
        system.debug('The sObjectType is  'Some Custom Object');
        continue;
     }

It should go without saying I am not super experienced with Apex development - I need to know if it is even possible to do what I intend here or if I should instead implement the trigger on the custom object itself. In which case I am not sure how to even reference the attachment being created if there's no direct relationship between the two. Greatly appreciate any guidance

Your approach is correct. When uploading a new attachment to some entity it is true that 2 ContentDocumentLink records are being created, one for the creating user and one for the target entity.

Thus said your check LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() will correctly filter just the link to your target object. The LinkedEntityId contains relation to the target object being attached to. And the ContentDocumentId contains relation to the target attached file.
Creating trigger on target object won't work because attaching file won't trigger any change on that object.
Once you gather the ContentDocumentId you can use it inside your email notification.

Thank you for the feedback - however I don't observe my 2nd debug statement in the log with the sObject check on being equal to the custom object. If I change the IF statement to NOT EQUALS then it runs the rest of the code because it is equal to the User object. I don't observe the behavior that a ContentDocumentLInk Record is being recreated in reference to the target object.

How exactly you are attaching the file? When I manually attach file to Contact record it creates the 2 links i've shared.

Disregard my previous comment - I got it working correctly.
